# Deploying Watson Visual recognition app fails

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson, visual-recognition

I created some custom classifiers locally and then i try to deploy on bluemix an app that classifies an image based on the classifiers i made.

When I try to deploy it, it failes to start.

```
import os
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 
import time
start_time = time.time()

visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(VisualRecognitionV3.latest_version, api_key='*************')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './test170.jpg'), 'rb') as image_file:
 print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.classify(images_file=image_file,threshold=0, classifier_ids=['Angle_971786581']), indent=2))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Even if I try to deploy a simple print , it failes to deploy, but the starter app i get from bluemix, or a Flask tutorial (https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/03/simple-hello-world-python-app-using-flask/) i found online deploy just fine.

I'm very new to web programming and using cloud services so i'm totally lost.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to rule out your code. Try running the code locally and see if that works first. Otherwise it is more a Bluemix app issue, in which case you may need to post logs relating to the error.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty My code runs locally just fine. When I try to deploy, I can't get anything useful from the post logs, just that the app has crashed. By the way i get the logs from the option inside the platform cause  cf logs appname --recent is giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemix is expecting your python application to serve on a port. If your application isn't serving some kind of response on the port, it assumes the application failed to start.

```
# On Bluemix, get the port number from the environment variable PORT
# When running this app on the local machine, default the port to 8080
port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080))


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World! I am running on port ' + str(port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

It looks like you're writing your code to just execute once and stop. Instead, make it do the work when someone hits your URL, like shown in the hello_world() function above.

Think about what you want to happen when someone goes to YOUR_APP_NAME.mybluemix.net

If you do not want your application to be a WEB application, but instead just execute once (a background worker application), then use the --no-route option at the end of your cf push command. Then, look at the logs using `cf logs appname --recent` to see the output of your application

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#deployingapps

Comment: I have already tried running with --no-route, with no success but I'm gonna try again following the instructions from the link. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the use of `VCAP_APP_PORT` environment variable is deprecated and will not work in future versions of Cloud Foundry, you should use `PORT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was watson-developer-cloud module, giving me an error that it could not be found.

I downgraded to python version 2.7.12, installing it for all users.
Modified runtime.exe and requirments.txt (requirments.txt possible not needed)
Staged with Diego, using no-route and set-health-check APP_NAME none command.

Those fixed the problem, but i still get an exit status 0.

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy an app in bluemix,you should have a requirements.txt which include services you used in your app. 
so ,you should checkout your requirements.txt,maybe you lost

```
watson_developer_cloud
```

and then, the requirements.txt likes this:

```
Flask==0.10.1
watson_developer_cloud
```